# Convert Json code to php array

Tags: php, json

Here is my json code :

```
    {
    "Parameter": {
        "LookupName": "EmailAddress",
        "LookupValue": "$a"
    },
    "Columns": {
        "Include_CSV": "ProspectID",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": "",
        "EmailAddress": ""
    },
    "Sorting": {
        "ColumnName": "FirstName",
        "Direction": "1"
    },
    "Paging": {
        "Offset": 0,
        "RowCount": 200
    }
}
```

I need to write Php array for this Json Code. can any one help? Advance Thanks..

Comment: have you tried json_decode()

Comment: after `"Parameter":` there needs to be a curly brace: `"Parameter":{`

Comment: yes, sorry for that again i changed

Comment: also: did you copy/paste that code? because the quotes are also invalid for json `”` should be `"`

Answer (score 2):

```
$json = '{"apples":"green","bananas":"yellow"}';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

Will be:

```
Array
(
    [apples] => green
    [bananas] => yellow
)
```

I'm passing true in the json_decode function, because othertwise it's a stdClass object. Your choice what you like more.

//Edit:

His JSON string **was** invalid, thats why PHP couldn't convert it. Fixed one:

```
{
    "Parameter": {
        "LookupName": "EmailAddress",
        "LookupValue": "example@example.com"
    },
    "Columns": {
        "Include_CSV": "ProspectID",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": "",
        "EmailAddress": ""
    },
    "Sorting": {
        "ColumnName": "FirstName",
        "Direction": "1"
    },
    "Paging": {
        "Offset": 0,
        "RowCount": 200
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried like this but my code shows empty.

Comment: You are using `“` instead of `"`.

Comment: $json = '{

"Parameter"{:"LookupName":"EmailAddress","LookupValue":"example@example.com"},

"Columns":{"Include_CSV":"ProspectID","FirstName","LastName","EmailAddress"},

"Sorting":{"ColumnName":"FirstName","Direction":"1"},

"Paging":{"Offset":0,"RowCount":200}

}';
var_dump(json_decode($json,true));

Comment: i tried like that but it shows NULL

Comment: Your JSON string is invalid. That's why PHP can't convert it. Try http://jsonlint.com/ to fix it.

Comment: Fixed JSON: `{
    "Parameter": {
        "LookupName": "EmailAddress",
        "LookupValue": "example@example.com"
    },
    "Columns": {
        "Include_CSV": "ProspectID",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": "",
        "EmailAddress": ""
    },
    "Sorting": {
        "ColumnName": "FirstName",
        "Direction": "1"
    },
    "Paging": {
        "Offset": 0,
        "RowCount": 200
    }
}` works fine for me.

Comment: yes your correct my json code was wrong thanks for your help

Comment: Feel free to mark it as answer then :-)

Answer (score 1):

read this article i hope it is useful for you

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Or

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_string, TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$jsonRes = $_REQUEST['YoutJsonResponse'];
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonRes, true);
echo json_last_error();
```

This will parse json and give error if it has any. Your json doesn't seem to be correct.

`json_decode($jsonRes, true);` return `array` instead of `object`.